# How can I use @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes to instantiate Classes with different configurations?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to create a config file that will allow me to define different data generators, each of which will need a different configuration.  But, they all share the same method, `generateRow`, so these classes can all implement an interface.  I'm using Jackson version 2.9.4.

To illustrate, here's two sample config files:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "standard",
        "config": {
            "rows": 1000,
            "columns": 10
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "totalSize",
        "config": {
            "sizeInBytes": 1073741824,
            "cellDensityInBytes": 12,
            "columns": 5
        }
    }
}
```

The first data generator simply creates a file with the given number of rows and columns, the second generator creates a file of a pre-defined size, determining the number of rows needed to satisfy the configured variables (i.e., number of columns and cell density).

So, I created an interface:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes.Type;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.As;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.Id;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = IGenerateRows.PROPERTY, defaultImpl = StandardRowGenerator.class)
@JsonSubTypes(value = { @Type(StandardRowGenerator.class) })
public interface IGenerateRows {

    public static final String PROPERTY = "type";

    public String[] generateRow();
}
```

And I have at least one concrete implementation:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;

@JsonTypeName(value = StandardRowGenerator.TYPE)
public class StandardRowGenerator {

    public static final String TYPE = "standard";

    private static final String ROWS = "rows";
    private static final String COLUMNS = "columns";

    @JsonProperty(value = ROWS, required = true)
    private int rows;

    @JsonProperty(value = COLUMNS, required = true)
    private int columns;
}
```

What I cannot figure out, is how to handle the `config` node of a data generator node in my configuration file.  How would I correctly set up my concrete classes to define the properties they need to generate data?

In my bootstrap code, I instantiate the entire config object as follows:

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(inputStream, DataGeneratorConfig.class);
```

For brevity, I've omitted getters and setters, and the rest of the config file which isn't pertinent to the question at-hand.  If I can provide any additional details or code, let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a little unsure about the underlying implementation of your classes and what data they are genearting etc.

But you are along the right sort of lines, I've pushed what I think is a working example of what you are looking to this repo, note this is using https://projectlombok.org/ to generate the POJOs because Im lazy.

https://github.com/Flaw101/jackson-type-info

- it will ignore the "data" node. This is mostly because again Im lazy, the entities could be wrapped in a `Data` class to handle it. The ObjectMapper in the test enables the features required for this.
- It will read/write the data of the config classes. Inline with the exampels you've specified.
- There's no quick wins for automagically desearlizing the data. You could maybe just write it to a map -> Object but that's incredibly messy and with tools like lombok/IDE class geneartion making these entities should be seconds of work.

The `IGenerateRow` looks like,

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = RowGenerator.PROPERTY, defaultImpl = StandardRowGenerator.class)
@JsonSubTypes(value = { @Type(StandardRowGenerator.class), @Type(TotalSizeGeneartor.class) })
@JsonRootName(value = "data")
public abstract interface RowGenerator {

    public static final String PROPERTY = "type";

    Config getConfig();
}
```

And Config is just a marker interface for the concrete impls.

```
public interface Config {



}
```

The SimpleTypeGenerator now becomes,

```
@JsonTypeName(value = StandardRowGenerator.TYPE)
@Data

public class StandardRowGenerator implements RowGenerator {

    public static final String TYPE = "standard";

    private StandardConfig config;

    @Data
    public static class StandardConfig implements Config {
        private int rows;
        private int columns;
    }
}
```

And similar for `TotalSize`,

```
@JsonTypeName(value = TotalSizeGeneartor.TYPE)
@Data
public class TotalSizeGeneartor implements RowGenerator {

    public static final String TYPE = "totalSize";

    private TotalSizeConfig config;

    @Data
    public static class TotalSizeConfig implements Config {
        private long sizeInBytes;
        private int cellDensityInBytes;
        private int columns;
    }
}
```

These could be improved with more/better generic type information to be able to get the concrete references to config.

The test class reads your two configs in the resource folder, writes them to the object and back to a string comparing the before/after, that there is no null or empty properties, and that the interfaces are of the correct implementation.

Note, this uses the `assertThat` from `AssertJ`

```
public class JacksonTest {

    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    private String json;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeserStandard() throws Exception {
        json = StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(
                new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/main/resources/standard.json")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        RowGenerator generator = mapper.readValue(json, RowGenerator.class);
        assertThat(generator).hasNoNullFieldsOrProperties().isExactlyInstanceOf(StandardRowGenerator.class);
        assertThat(generator.getConfig()).hasNoNullFieldsOrProperties().isExactlyInstanceOf(StandardConfig.class);
        assertThat(json).isEqualTo(mapper.writeValueAsString(generator));
        System.out.println(generator);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeserTotalsize() throws Exception {
        json = StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(
                new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/main/resources/totalsize.json")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        RowGenerator generator = mapper.readValue(json, RowGenerator.class);
        assertThat(generator).hasNoNullFieldsOrProperties().isExactlyInstanceOf(TotalSizeGeneartor.class);
        assertThat(generator.getConfig()).hasNoNullFieldsOrProperties().isExactlyInstanceOf(TotalSizeConfig.class);
        assertThat(json).isEqualTo(mapper.writeValueAsString(generator));
        System.out.println(generator);

    }

}
```